Package dependencies from current reactor separately from downloaded dependencies
I'd like to have two assemblies:
one with just the dependencies that are part of current multi-module build
 <dependencySets>                                              
    <dependencySet>                                           
        <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>         
        <includes>                                            
            <!-- include only artifacts that were built by current reactor -->
        </includes>                                           
    </dependencySet>                                          
</dependencySets>                                             

another one with all other dependencies:
 <dependencySets>                                              
    <dependencySet>                                           
        <excludes>                                            
            <!-- exclude artifacts that were built by current reactor -->
        </exclude>                                           
    </dependencySet>                                          
</dependencySets>                                             

is it possible?
As a workaround I'm using <include>${project.groupId}:*</include> which relies on all modules sharing the same group.

Why do you want to have that?

I'm trying to create a docker image in similar way to this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/packaging/container-images/efficient-images.html
I don't want to pull in all of spring boot though
